# Hovering message with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a script that does a plot with plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame with X, Y, and f values
df= pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [10, 12, 5, 8, 6], 'x2': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7],'y2':[2,5,3,1,8],'f':[1,2,3,4,5]})

hover_text1 = df.apply(lambda row: f'({row["x"]},{row["y"]}) at {row["f"]}', axis=1)
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.x, y= df.y, mode='lines+markers', text=hover_text1, name='data1', line=dict(color='orange',width=linewidth),marker=dict(symbol='circle', size=markersize),hoverinfo='text'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.x2, y= df.y2, mode='lines+markers', name='data2', line=dict(color='green',width=linewidth),marker=dict(symbol='circle', size=markersize)))

# Customize the layout or add additional settings as needed
fig.update_layout(title='Plotly Scatter Plot', xaxis_title='X-axis', yaxis_title='Y-axis', showlegend=True)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Unfortunately I cannot capture a image of the hovering but if you run it you see you have two lines (one orange, the other green)
When you hover over the orange one you get "(X,Y) at f" message which is fine.

But when you hover over the green one you get the default "(X,Y)" and then in inverted color the name of the curve. However once you customize the hover message this name disapears (like in the orange one)

My question is, how can I customize the hover message as the orange one, but without losing the nice inverted color message with the data name?

EDIT: clarification
For clarity I changed the name of `hover_text2` to `hover_text1` (since it goes for `data1`)

When hovering in `data2` I see (X,Y) and the name "data2" in inverted colors

What I want is to see:

- In `data1` I want to see (X,Y) at f and then the nice "data1" name in inverted colors  (as you see in data2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but you haven't defined a hover_text1 variable

```
hover_text1 = df.apply(lambda row: f'({row["x"]},{row["y"]}) at {row["f"]}', axis=1)
```

Comment: You can notice I only use a `hover_text2` variable. I should have renamed that but you can see that has no impact on the code

Comment: should I edit the question for clarity?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Do you want to see the name "data2" in the same formatting as the point (X,Y)?

Comment: I am sorry, I will edit the code and add some clarification.  I added an Edit with clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`hovertemplate`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-hovertemplate) directly :

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.x, y= df.y, mode='lines+markers', text=hover_text1, 
                         name='data1', line=dict(color='orange',width=linewidth),
                         marker=dict(symbol='circle', size=markersize),
                         hovertemplate='%{text}<extra>%{fullData.name}</extra>'))
```

- `%{text}` refers to the data assigned via `text` keyword, `%{fullData.name}` to the trace name.
- `<extra>...</extra>` is the "secondary box", that part of the hover where the trace name is usually displayed in a contrasting color (the tag must be set empty to hide the secondary box completely).

Note that setting `hoverinfo='text'` is a shortcut for `hovertemplate=%{text}<extra></extra>`.

See also [Customizing hover text with a hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate)